# Grouping rows and combining data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that returns 3 columns like below:

```
Second ref   Code    Description 
10/14/0094  ZW01008  Side Support Bracket PM1662TAA
10/14/0095  ZW01008  Rear Hook LH PM1664TAA
10/14/0095  ZW01008  Rear Hook LH PM1664TAA
10/14/0095  ZW01008  Rear Hook RH PM1663TAA
10/14/0095  ZW01008  Rear Hook RH PM1663TAA 
10/14/0096  ZW01008  Sunblind Brackets PM1665TAA
10/14/0098  ZW01008  NEW TOOL TRIAL 300 HALFS 600 WEDGES
10/14/0100  ZW01008  NEW TOOL TRIAL WATER RESERVOIR
```

If there are multiple rows with the same `SecondRef` I want to group those rows together and either only have one of the `Description` values showings, as they will be a variation of each other, or combine the the values of all 4 of the records in to one record.

Here is the query I have used to get the example:

```
SELECT  AllocationBalance.SecondRef, StockItem.Code, BomRecord.Description
FROM    AllocationBalance AS AllocationBalance 
INNER JOIN StockItem AS StockItem ON AllocationBalance.ItemID = StockItem.ItemID
INNER JOIN BomAllocation ON AllocationBalance.Reference = BomAllocation.AllocationNumber 
INNER JOIN WopOrder ON BomAllocation.BomAllocationID = WopOrder.BomAllocationID 
INNER JOIN BomRecord ON WopOrder.BomRecordID = BomRecord.BomRecordID
WHERE     (AllocationBalance.RecipientName = 'BOM') AND (StockItem.Code LIKE '%ZW01008%')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `GROUP BY` and `MAX` or `MIN`:

```
SELECT AllocationBalance.SecondRef, 
       StockItem.Code, 
       MAX(dbo.BomRecord.Description) as Description
FROM [YOUR_TABLES] -- including joins
WHERE (AllocationBalance.RecipientName = 'BOM') AND (StockItem.Code LIKE '%ZW01008%')
GROUP BY AllocationBalance.SecondRef, StockItem.Code
```

So grouping by the first 2 columns and taking the last/highest value in the description column.

Using `MAX` instead of `MIN` would cover you in cases where you might have an empty description as @Gordon mentions in the comments.

Comment: @Tanner . . . I would be inclined to use `max()` instead of `min()`.  That way if one of the descriptions is an empty string, you will choose something else.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, it's a good point, have amended answer to include that.

Answer (score 0):

Try DISTINCT.
If i understand correctly- that is what you need.

Comment: Better not - first this doesn't work with some uninmportant columns having different values, second you have absolutely no control about query results. SQL has 'group by' operator for these things. 'distinct' keyword is pretty usable for quick ad-hoc queries to check something in SSMS, so can it be used in expressions like 'count(distinct something)' - but not as poor-man replacement of 'group by'.