# Select row value if it's the same for every row in group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with join and group-by that returns something like this:

```
CONSTRUCTOR | MODEL | COLOR
------------+-------+------
Mercedes    | SLK   | Gray
Ferrari     | 430   | Red
Mercedes    | GLK   | Black
Porsche     | 911   | Blue
Ferrari     | 458   | Red
```

I'd like to add a group by `CONSTRUCTOR` and get the value of the color if it's the same in each group or "multiple" if there are multiple values (not interested in `MODEL`)

```
CONSTRUCTOR | COLOR
------------+---------
Mercedes    | multiple
Ferrari     | Red
Porsche     | Blue
```

This query works, but I wonder if there is a more efficent way to achieve the same result without complicating the query itself

```
SELECT
  CONSTRUCTOR,
  CASE COUNT(DISTINCT COLOR)
    WHEN 1 THEN MIN(COLOR)
    ELSE 'multiple'
  END AS COLOR
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CONSTRUCTOR
```

I think that I cannot avoid the `MIN` (or `MAX`) as per this [closely related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715582/).

Can I avoid the `CASE` or use it in a more efficent way?

Comment: Your query looks fine, expect for that `DISTINCT` is **not** a function. I.e. do `COUNT(DISTINCT COLOR)` to make things clearer.

Comment: Thank you, fixed

Comment: I do not see any problem here. some DB have first to use with group by, you can maybe use it instead of min. But otherwise, it is juste fine.

Comment: I don't think there is a more effective way than the one you are using to be honest.

Comment: Your solution seems fine. You could get something similar by joining a cte but it'd be less efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way to write the query is:

```
SELECT CONSTRUCTOR,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(COLOR) = MAX(COLOR) THEN MIN(COLOR)
             ELSE 'multiple'
        END) AS COLOR
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CONSTRUCTOR;
```

In general, `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is more expensive than other aggregation functions.  Using just `MIN()` and `MAX()` should be a bit more efficient.  There is almost no overhead to using `CASE`.

If the values can be `NULL`, you can take that into account with an additional condition:

```
SELECT CONSTRUCTOR,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(COLOR) = MAX(COLOR) AND COUNT(COLOR) = COUNT(*)
             THEN MIN(COLOR)
             ELSE 'multiple'
        END) AS COLOR
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY CONSTRUCTOR;
```

Comment: When the two are batched together this is 8% more efficient (46% of the batch)

Comment: I worried about `MIN`/`MAX` performance, it turns out that `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is slower.

Answer (score 1):

[CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) at rescue:

```
With g as (
  select
    CONSTRUCTOR, 
    count(distinct color) as n_colors,
    max(color) as color
  from MYTABLE
  group by CONSTRUCTOR
)
select CONSTRUCTOR, 
       case when n_colors = 1 then color
       else 'multiple' end
from g;
```

**Explanation**: you can cook your data in a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) sentence and then make the final query with pre-cooked data in a simple way. CTE is your friend.

**Notice**: the elegant way looks to be windowed functions. But `count( distinct` is not allowed on `over partition` clause.

**EDIT** Edited due OP comment:

You can avoid max using `first_value` windowed function:

```
With g1 as (
  select
    CONSTRUCTOR, 
    count(distinct color) as n_colors
  from t
  group by cons
),
g2 as (
  select distinct
    CONSTRUCTOR,
    first_Value(color) over (partition by cons order by color) as color
  from t
)  
select g1.cons, 
       case when g1.n_colors = 1 then g2.color
       else 'multiple' end
from g1 inner join g2 on g1.CONSTRUCTOR = g2.CONSTRUCTOR
```

**FINAL ANSWER**

Without `group by`, using windowed functions, also index friendly ( by CONSTRUCTOR and COLOR ) :

```
with cte as (
 select 
    CONSTRUCTOR,
    first_Value(color) over (partition by CONSTRUCTOR order by color 
                             rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                                          UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING   ) as f,
    last_Value(color) over (partition by CONSTRUCTOR order by color  
                            rows BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
                                         UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING  ) as l,
    ROW_NUMBER ( ) over (partition by CONSTRUCTOR order by color  ) as n       
  from t
) 
select CONSTRUCTOR, 
       case when f=l then f else 'multiple' end as color
from cte       
where n = 1;
```

Comment: My execution plan shows this answer has the same plan as the original query posed. So no better.

Comment: oh! yea. sorry. wait ;)

Comment: @Paul, I just edited answer with my final approach. Is also index friendly. I guess I'm proud about it. Check for performance and execution plan.

Comment: +1 for showing the use of `FISRT`/`LAST_VALUE`. However I prefer the [Gordon Linoff's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47905208/9112696) which is shorter and more manteinable